# Excel not properly displaying an array

Tags: vb.net, excel, automation

Excel seems to display the first element of an array over and over in a column with the following code

```
      Dim fileNum() As String = {"1", "2"}
    xlSourceRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("N2:N" & fileNum.Length + 1)
    xlSourceRange.Value2 = fileNum
```

The entire range just fills up with 1. How can I make it so each element in the array is displayed in the column without having to manually assign each cell in a loop. I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Excel if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now i got to an IDE so I can answer more intelligently.
The problem is the array - Unfortunately, Excel adds ranges based upon a 2-d array.
For your specific example, this bit of code would give you what you are looking for:

```
    Dim fileNum() As object = {{"1"}, {"2"}}
    xlSourceRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("N2:N" & fileNum.Length + 1)
    xlSourceRange.Value = fileNum
```

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: You should edit your original answer if you think this is the correct approach. Alternatively delete your previous answer.

Comment: It worked thank you so very much. I was wondering how would you convert a one dimensional array of objects to a 2-D array of objects?

Comment: Just create a new array - Dim x(,) as Object - Then you can populate it using a for loop.